# Euler equation with single state variables

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, navier-stokes

I want to simulate a flow using the Euler equations. For this reason I'm wondering if there's a modified version of the Euler equations.

At the moment my formula looks like this:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho \\ \rho v_1 \\ \rho v_2 \\ \rho v_3 \\ \rho E
\end{pmatrix}
= -\mathrm{div}
\begin{pmatrix} \rho v_1 & \rho v_2 & \rho v_3 \\ 
\rho v_1^2 + p & \rho v_1 v_2 & \rho v_1 v_3 \\ 
\rho v_2 v_1 & \rho v_2^2 + p & \rho v_2 v_3 \\ 
\rho v_3 v_1 & \rho v_3 v_2 & \rho v_3^2 + p \\ 
(\rho E + p) v_1 & (\rho E + p) v_2 & (\rho E + p) v_3
\end{pmatrix} $$

Since the state variables are all in combination with the density, I need a division to calculate the flow. So what I actually would like to get is something like this:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \begin{pmatrix} \rho \\ v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ E \end{pmatrix} $$

Can someone help?

Comment: Hi Thomas, and welcome to Physics Stackexchange! I fixed up the formatting of your equations, but please make sure I got it right. In particular, I think you were missing the time derivative, and also standard notation is that $\vec{v} = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ (note the lack of arrows over the components).

Comment: What do you mean "a division to calculate flow?"

Comment: You have written the equations in conservative form, from your question it sounds like you are asking for non-conservative form. See this related [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70496/21144).

Comment: If what OSE is correct in his interpretation off your question, I would argue that you don't want it that way. You want to solve the conservative equations (computationally easier) and *output* the state variables ($\rho, \vec v, p$).

Comment: I want to do the calculation using finite-volume method on a fpga. This means that I need the speed alone, not multiplied by rho. But I dont want to use a division, cause of the timing. I've looked up the conservation forms. I've done some changings and now it looks like this:

$$
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t} = -u_j \nabla u_i - \frac{1}{\rho} \nabla p
$$

$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = - \nabla (u_i * E) - \nabla (p * u_i)
$$

So with this form I it would be possible to calculate the flow without using a division as long as p depends on the density.

Do u agree?

Comment: can please somebody help me?